# How to use nested for loop in vue.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a data in following format and want to loop the data and map the data what we have inside the array.

```js
{
    tableEmployeeList : {
        01 : { 
            missing : [
                {
                    empId: 1
                }
            ]
        },
        02 : {
            missing: [
                {
                    empId: 2
                }
            ]
        },
        03: {
            missing : [
                {
                    empId: 3
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Tried using this logic but was getting an error as employee not defined

```
<tr v-for="employee in tableEmployeeList" :key="employee.empId">
    <tr v-for="data in employee" :key="data.empId">
        <td class="td-empId">{{ data.empId }}</td>
    </tr>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use key employee.id
Basically you can use anything as a key for example employee.name employee.age

sharing a sample of for loop in vue js

`<div v-for="item in data" :key="item.id">`